# Error al iniciar android studio

Tags: android

Tengo este mensaje de error:

> Error:Process 'command
>   '/home/chiclenano/Descargas/android-studio/jre/bin/java'' finished
>   with non-zero exit value 2

Hola buenas tardes, espero que me den alguna respuesta a este error, no sé qué hacer, se agradece mucho si alguien sabe..

Comment: Hola Kevin, ¿usas alguna librería dentro de tu proyecto?

Comment: @Kevin eliminé mi respuesta, **creo que es necesario agregues tu build.gradle**, ya que el error no es en java.exe.